# Focus on textbox after a keyevent

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to achieve is  :

- On <kbd>Alt</kbd> it should show a `span` which would tell user that if <kbd>c</kbd> is pressed now, the `textbox` will be on `focus`
- Or on <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> it should `focus`. (this works)

**Issue** :
When <kbd>Alt</kbd> is pressed `span` shows, and when <kbd>c</kbd> is followed nothing happens. But if I press <kbd>c</kbd> after I click somewhere on the page it sets the focus. Why is that? And how do i fix this?

Below is what I have.

```js
var lastKey;
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (e.altKey) {
    $(".shortcut").fadeIn("slow");
    if (e.keyCode == 67) { // c
      console.log("filter should open");
      $(".shortcut").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#item").focus()
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

  }
  if (lastKey && e.keyCode == 67) { // c
    $(".shortcut").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#item").focus()
    e.preventDefault();
    lastKey = false;
    return false;
  }
  lastKey = true;
});
```

```css
.shortcut {
  display: none;
}

.inputgroup-shortcut {
  position: absolute;
  //top: 25%;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background: #428bca;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.0;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="shortcut inputgroup-shortcut">c</span>
<input type="text" id="item" />
```

Comment: Your code works fine as it is in Chrome - although the logic can be simplified.

Comment: It won't for me. Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: I'm on the same version too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I got the behavior said by PO in (https://jsfiddle.net/gwkfd6m1/)[Fiddle]

Comment: @JinsPeter that works for me. Maybe I'm just not getting what the issue is, or the steps to reproduce it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you pressed <kbd>alt</kbd> released it, the `span` shows and now if you press <kbd>c</kbd> the focus is set ?

Comment: That's correct. I am using OSX though

Comment: Ah, ok, the problem is apparent on Windows. However, I'd say this is not how chords are designed to work. The behaviour of press ALT, release, press C would not be correct IMO. It should be effective for ALT + C only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent alt key from performing it's default action in the browser i.e to show the menu bar in the browser.

```js
var lastKey;
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (e.altKey) {
    $(".shortcut").fadeIn("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 67) { // c
      console.log("filter should open");
      $(".shortcut").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#item").focus()
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

  }
  if (lastKey && e.keyCode == 67) { // c
    $(".shortcut").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#item").focus()
    e.preventDefault();
    lastKey = false;
    return false;
  }
  lastKey = true;
});
```

```js
var lastKey;
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (e.altKey) {
    $(".shortcut").fadeIn("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 67) { // c
      console.log("filter should open");
      $(".shortcut").fadeOut("slow");
      $("#item").focus()
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }

  }
  if (lastKey && e.keyCode == 67) { // c
    $(".shortcut").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#item").focus()
    e.preventDefault();
    lastKey = false;
    return false;
  }
  lastKey = true;
});
```

```css
.shortcut {
  display: none;
}

.inputgroup-shortcut {
  position: absolute;
  //top: 25%;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background: #428bca;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.0;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="shortcut inputgroup-shortcut">c</span>
<input type="text" id="item" />
```